# Unknown syntax error near "wait for" statement VHDL

Tags: syntax, vhdl, state-machine, vivado, test-bench

My "wait for" statements in my test bench code are producing syntax errors, and I am unable to trace down the source of the error to fix it. The error that it is producing is:

`Error: Syntax error near 'wait' Error: type error near ns ; current type time; expected type void Error: 'ns' is not a subprogram`

Which I am not understanding since all examples including in a textbook for examples using the `wait` and `wait for` statements has been the exact same that I am using.

I've been looking at this testbench file for forever trying to figure out what this syntax error is. I can't determine if it is something earlier in my code with using an incorrect type, or missing a punctuation mark or what. This is supposed to just be a testbench for a state machine that will switch between add, subtract, multiply.
A & B are 4 bit inputs, SEL is a button that when it is a 1 the state changes, and the CLK uses rising edge to pass any changes. Result is a 8 bit output.

I am even unable to run a simulation to test the entity and architecture as when I try to run the simulation on Vivado it won't because of the syntax near the wait statement. For context, in the code snippet below, the only underlined issue that Vivado has with it is by the `wait for 10ns;` line. If I format it as `wait for 10 ns;` it produces identical errors.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity HW9_TB is

end HW9_TB;

architecture Behavioral of HW9_TB is

    component HW9 is
    Port ( A : in signed (3 downto 0);
           B : in signed (3 downto 0);
           SEL : in STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           Result : out signed (7 downto 0);
           CLK : in STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

    signal A : signed (3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal B : signed (3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal SEL : std_logic := '0';
    signal CLK : std_logic := '0';

begin

    T1 : HW9 PORT MAP (
        A => A, B => B, SEL => SEL, CLK => CLK);
        
-- A=0, B=0, SEL=0, CLK=0
    A <=    "0000";     
    B <=    "0000"; 
    SEL <=  '0';    
    CLK <=  '0';    
    wait for 10ns;
```

Comment: A wait statement is a sequential statement. It shows up here in the architecture body in a place of concurrent statements. The wait statement and possibly preceding signal assignments should be in a process statement.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: In addition to a process statement [there's a concurrent procedure call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s129X.jpg) in this case with signal parameters of mode out for A, B, SEL and CLK. Without any signal parameters of mode in to use in a sensitivity list the process would execute only once. Concurrent statements represent block and/or process statement equivalents which have drivers for any signals assigned, so you'd assign values to a particular signal in one process.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the information you've provided has been very helpful. It seems that the main issue was that the statements were not in a process block, which I did not know they needed to be. I can now run simulations and debug my logic so thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in your code:

1. `wait` is a sequential statement only allowed in a `process`, but you wrote it as a concurrent statement. Just think what it should mean outside of a process? All concurrent statements are executed in parallel.
2. The unit of the time needs to be separated from the value by white space.

A boiled-down and corrected version of your issue is:

```vhdl
entity TB is
end TB;

architecture Behavioral of TB is
begin
    --wait for 10 ns; -- Produces an error message, because not allowed here.

    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns; -- Here it is allowed.
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that wait statements had to be in process blocks. Since I've put it in a process block the syntax error has cleared up and I can run simulations and debug, I appreciate the help!

Comment: It was a pleasure to help, good luck! Please understand that VHDL is not a _programming_ language, it is a _description_ language. You can write stuff that looks like a (sequential) program, but most of it is only possible in simulations.